# Freeze hover onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, hover

```
 $(".somediv").hover(
     function() {
         $(this).animate({'margin-top':'100px'},1000);
     },
     function() {
         $(this).animate...…
     }
 );
 $(".somediv").click(function ....????
```

The question is how can I freeze the animation on click in the margin-top:100px state not letting onmouseout function to happen after somediv was clicked

But next click should unfreeze the hover functions 
Thanks on advance

---

stop() doesn't help to prevent unhovering

```
$("#one.button").hover(function() {
$(this).animate({'margin-top':'30px'},{queue:false,duration:700});
}, function() {
$(this).animate({'margin-top':'10px'},{queue:false,duration:700});
  });

$("#one.button").click(function(){
$("#one.button").stop().animate({'margin-left':'0px'},{queue:false, duration:700});
 });
```

after click #one.button is animated to margin-left:0px and after that it is unhovered to margin-top:10px

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 $(".somediv").click(function() {
   $(this).stop()
 });
```

See here for more info:

http://api.jquery.com/stop/